# Translation from Perl to Python, brief

Tags: python, perl, translation, range, min

I really need help on this. I tried translating this Perl into Python, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Thanks!

Perl:

```perl
@X_max = &MaxValue(@xCoords);
     $maxX = int(10 * $X_max[0]/5);
    @X_min = &MinValue(@xCoords);
    $minX =  int(10 * $X_min[0]/5);
    $rangeX = &Range($minX, $maxX);
    print GRID "X:\t $maxX\t $minX\t\t $rangeX\n";
```

Python (so far):

```py
_max = max(xCoords) 
max(X) = int(10 * max((X)0/5))
X_min = min(xcoords)
min(X) = int(10 * min((X)0/5))
range(X) = range(min(X), max(X))
print('X:') ('%4s') % min, '%15s' % max, '%25s' % range
```

Comment: Can you post what you already tried?

Comment: sure, _max = max(xCoords) 
max(X) = int(10 * max((X)0/5))
X_min = min(xcoords)
min(X) = int(10 * min((X)0/5))
range(X) = range(min(X), max(X))
print('X:') ('%4s') % min, '%15s' % max, '%25s' % range

Comment: this is the crappy version, right now im working to improve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Perl does not look like it's simply the Python `min`, `max`, and `range` functions. Because `MaxValue` returns a *list* of values, which is disregarded in the next step as the code simply takes the first item in the list. So it might be something like this:

```
x_max  = max( xcoords );
maxx   = int( 10 * x_max / 5 );
x_min  = min( xcoords );
minx   = int( 10 * x_min / 5 );
rangex = range( minx, maxx );
grid.write(  "X:\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(minX, maxX, rangeX));
```

Or even:

```
rangex = range( 2 * min( xcoords ), 2 * max( xcoords ));
```

However, the range seems to indicate that it's simply a simple variable, perhaps just `maxx - minx + 1`. So I don't think Python `range` will work.

This is over-complex code, to say the least: `10 * x / 5 <=> 2 * x`.

Answer (score 1):

I suck at Perl, I don't know what does Range() do, but I tried and I wrote this:

```
X_max = []
X_min = []
for i in xCoords:
    X_max.append(i.max)
    X_min.append(i.min)
maxX = 10 * X_max[0] / 5
minX = 10 * X_min[0] / 5
rangeX = range(minX, maxX)
out = "X:\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(minX, maxX, rangeX)
#now you can do print out -OR- open('./file', 'w').write(out)
```

Comment: the range is supposed to count the amount of numbers in the set

Comment: `Range()` is non-standard Perl. And the `&` before every function is Perl 4 hangover.